# Downcasing user input makes gsub() prone to errors

Tags: ruby

I have discovered a bug that occurs when downcase() and gsub() are run in concert. The following code works just fine as long as the user input contains at least one capital letter. However, when run with input that contains no capital letters, I get the error "undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass"

```
print("Favorite Animal: ")
animal = gets.chomp().downcase!
if animal.include?("cat")
  animal.gsub!(/cat/, "dog")
end
print("Your favorite animal: #{animal}")
```

Comment: PSA: Ruby tends to omit empty argument lists, so `chomp()` becomes `chomp`.

Comment: _"[...] makes gsub() prone to errors"_ – `gsub` is never called, the error is raised from `include?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#method-i-downcase-21):

> **downcase!(*options) → self or nil**
> Downcases the characters in `self`; returns `self` if any changes were made, `nil` otherwise:

So if there was nothing to downcase, `#downcase!` returns `nil` as documented.

You want to use `#downcase` instead of `#downcase!`:

```
animal = gets.chomp().downcase
```

so that `animal` get the downcased string.

Comment: Kman, if you look through Ruby's [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html) methods you will find that many whose name ends with an explanation mark (which often, but not always, indicates the object is being modified in place) have this same behaviour: `nil` is returned when no change is made. This applies to some `Array` methods as well, such as [Array#select!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-select-21). Not all Rubiests are fond of that language design choice, but that's the way it is.

Comment: I made a temporary variable with the return value of downcase(), assigning its value to animal if and only if it is a non-nil value.

Comment: Note that the problem is merely due to the assignment. If you call the `!` methods in succession without assigning the result back to `animal`, everything works as expected, e.g. `animal = gets` followed by `animal.chomp!` and `animal.downcase!`.